# Sybase to MySQL automatic exportation

Tags: mysql, sql, sybase, database-migration

I have two databases: Sybase and MySQL. I need to export records to MySql when these are inserted in Sybase or export in some scheduled event. 
I've tried with output statement but this can not be used in triggers or procedures. 
Any suggestion to solve this problem?

Comment: Duplicate of http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/38782/how-can-i-migrate-a-sybase-database-to-mysql

Comment: disagree about duplicate.  the linked dba.stack question seems to have been as a one-off migration from sybase.  **this** question seems to be about an ongoing synch *("...when these are inserted...")* which is a different thing from a manual approach as recommended in linked question.

Answer (score 0):

(disclaimer, I've done similar things previously, but by no means would I consider the answer below the state of the art - just one possible approach

google around something like 'cross-database replication' or 'cross rdbms replication' to see who's done this before.

).

**I would first of all see if you can't score an ETL tool do the job without too much work**.  There are free open source ones and even things like Microsoft SSIS **might** work on non-MS databases.

If not, I would split this into different steps.

1. Find an appropriate Sybase output command that exports a subset of rows from one or more tables.  By subset I mean you need to be able to add a WHERE clause, not just do a full table dump.
2. Use an appropriate MySQL import script/command to load the data gotten out of step #1.  You may need to cycle back and forth between the 2 till you have something that works manually.
3. Write a Sybase trigger to insert lookup keys into a to-export table.  You want to store at least the tablename & source Sybase table's keys for each inserted row.  Use column names like key1_char, key2_char, not the actual column names, that makes it easier to extend to other source tables as needed.  **keep trigger processing as light as possible**.  What about updates btw?
4. Write a scheduled batch on Sybase side to run step #1 for the rows flagged in #3.
5. Write a scheduled batch on Mysql to import ,via #2, the results of #4.  Or kick it off from #4.

Another approach is to do the #3 flagging bit as needed, but use to drive one scheduled batch that SELECTs data from Sybase and INSERTs it into mysql directly.

You'll have to pick up the data from Sybase's SELECT and bind it manually to the INSERT of mysql.  But you probably get finer control over whats going on and you don't have to juggle 2 batches.  That's what I think a clever ETL would already be doing on your behalf.  Any half clever scripting language like php, python or ruby ought to handle it easily.  Especially important if you have things like surrogate/auto-generated keys.

Keep in mind that in both cases you'll have to either delete the to-export rows that you've successfully inserted or flag them as done.